# Changing the cell background color of a table within an alternating div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the proper syntax for changing the table cell background color of every-other div?

Code example:

```
            <table>    
                <div id="alternator">
                    <tr>
                        //stuff here
                    </tr>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    //stuff here
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </div>
            </table>
```

To explain, I have a part of my table wrapped in a Div with the id of `ALTERNATOR`
For every other ALTERNATOR that appears on the page, I want to change the background color of the table cells inside

Something like:

```
(#Alternator:odd).AllTableCellsInside().attr(background-color, "grey")
```

Comment: You can't wrap rows with divs.

Comment: Also you can't have several div's with the id alternator, id's must be unique. And id's are case sensitive. Your code example uses an all lowercase id, in your text you refer to it in all uppercase, and your "something like" example shows it in title-case.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, really, I do, but you could at least say something helpful rather than just telling me what I did wrong. And my code sample is just an example, it was designed to explain my question, not to be the answer in and of itself, so I didn't take the time to make sure it was correct. I'm sure you generally understand the gist of what I'm trying to do, and that's the information I'm after.

Comment: If you have a known set of rows that show be another color apply a class to each of the rows you want to be that color. There's no valid way in HTML to wrap or group rows together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the perfect use case for the `:odd` selector: http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

```
$('#alternator tr:odd').css('background-color', 'grey');
```

Comment: it's .css() to change background color :)

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to change every other table row, I just want to change everything inside of a certain section, alternating.

Comment: Thanks @wirey.  @proseidon, the odd selector selects every other element in the set and the elements do not have to be `tr`.  For example, `$('#alternator div:odd')` would select every other DIV within the DOM element with the ID of alternator.